# Getting Data into LLNL VisIt via Python

Tags: python, visualization

Without using VisIt's python library visit-writer.py, how can I import my data into VisIt? I'm aware of many [alternative file formats](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/FAQ.html#12) but I can't find a simple library that takes my arrays of data and just writes it as a file. Specifically, my data consists of adaptive mesh boxes (really, voxels) and so I figure is best represented by an unstructured data grid. For each voxel, I have to attach various scalar or vector variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From skimming the VisIt manual on "[Getting Data Into VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/1.5.4/GettingDataIntoVisIt1.5.4.pdf)", it seems like there are three basic ways to create VisIt-compatible data files:

1. For scalar data on a uniform grid, it is probably easiest to format your data for VisIt's BOV ("brick-of-values") database reader plugin.  This consists of a binary data file which is essentially a dump of the data array to disk, and a text-format header file which provides, among other things, the dimensions of the data, the type of the data, and the endian representation.
2. For simulation code written in C(++) or Fortran, the [Silo](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/silo/) library (also developed at LLNL) can be used to create VisIt-compatible data files.  "Getting Data Into VisIt" provides C and Fortran code examples for writing rectangular, curvilinear, point, and unstructured meshes using Silo.
3. For simulation code written in C(++) or Python, the `visit_writer` library can be used to save the data in VTK (Visualization Toolkit) format.

The short answer is that, even though you wanted to avoid using `visit_writer`, it is probably the easiest way for Python to save your data in a VisIt-compatible format.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that I would end up with visit-writer, alas. It's just that it requires a full-blown installation of VisIt, and that's been painful to setup. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a package called [pyvisfile](http://documen.tician.de/pyvisfile/) that is made to do this. I haven't tried it but it claims to work.